# three.js change object dynamically related to distance

Tags: three.js

I made a graphical website with three.js.

It's concept is universe that has so many texts.

When distance of between camera and mesh is close, mesh is text.

But if distance is far, it change to square.

I wonder that change mesh related to distance is possible?

I searched in google few hours, there is no information about this.

code here:

```js
// Define Variables
var myElement = document.getElementById("threejs");
let camera, scene, renderer;
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
clicked = new THREE.Vector2();
const target = new THREE.Vector2();
const windowHalf = new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 );
const moveState = {forward: 0, back: 0};
var isMobile = false;
var hold = -1;

/****** Define Function ******/
/*****************************/

checkMobile = () => {
  var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent;

  if (UserAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|Android|Windows CE|BlackBerry|Symbian|Windows Phone|webOS|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|POLARIS|IEMobile|lgtelecom|nokia|SonyEricsson/i) != null || UserAgent.match(/LG|SAMSUNG|Samsung/) != null) {
      isMobile = true;
  } else {
      isMobile = false;
  }
}
checkMobile();

onMouseMove = (event) => {
  mouse.x = ( (event.clientX/2) - (windowHalf.x/2) );
  mouse.y = ( (event.clientY/2) - (windowHalf.y/2) );
  clicked.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  clicked.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}


onResize = (event) => {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  
  windowHalf.set( width / 2, height / 2 );
 
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( width, height );
}

onContextMenu = (event) => { 
  event.preventDefault();
}

onMouseDown = (event) => {
  hold = event.which;
}

onMouseUp = () => {
  hold = -1;
};

// TEST

//

// Start Script
init = () => {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ transparent: true });
  
  if(isMobile) {
    var controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
  } else {
    console.log('isMobile false');
  }
  
  group = new THREE.Group();
  
  for ( let i = 0; i < 800; i ++ ) {   
    let sprite = new THREE.TextSprite({
      textSize: 2,
      redrawInterval: 1,
      texture: {
        text: 'TEST',
        fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
      },
      material: {
        color: 'white',
      },
    });
    sprite.position.x = Math.random() * 180-100;
    sprite.position.y = Math.random() * 180-100;
    sprite.position.z = Math.random() * 1000-40;
    group.add(sprite);

  }
  scene.add(group);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  
  // Event handler
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
  
  // Helper
  var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 15 );
  scene.add( axesHelper );

  animate = () => {
    // For camera follow mouse cursor
    target.x = ( 1 - mouse.x ) * 0.002;
    target.y = ( 1 - mouse.y ) * 0.002;
    camera.rotation.x += 0.05 * ( target.y - camera.rotation.x );
    camera.rotation.y += 0.05 * ( target.x - camera.rotation.y );
    
    if(isMobile) {
      controls.update();
    }
    switch(hold) {
      case 1:
        if(camera.position.z > 0) {
          camera.position.z -= 4;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        camera.position.z += 4;
        break;
    }
    
    // Object opacity related to distance between camera and object
    for (i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
      var distance = camera.position.distanceTo(group.children[i].position);
      var opacity = -1 / 400 * distance + 1;
      if (opacity < 0) {
        opacity = 0;
      }
      group.children[i].material.opacity = opacity;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }
  // Run
  animate();
}
// Run
init();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
/*  background: #11e8bb;  Old browsers */
/*  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #11e8bb 0%, #8200c9 100%);  FF3.6-15 */
/*  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #11e8bb 0%,#8200c9 100%);  Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
/*  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #11e8bb 0%,#8200c9 100%);  W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #ed1654, #f61e6c, #f76098);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#11e8bb', endColorstr='#8200c9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#threejs {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}
/* Header Left */
.header-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.header-left img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
/* Header Right */
.header-right {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
.header-right a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.header-right a:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
/* Main Company */
.down-btn {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.down-btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/* Section */
section {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--  <script src="three.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three.texttexture"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three.textsprite"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-left">
      <a href="#">MAIN</a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#">PRODUCT</a>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="threejs"></div>
  <script src="src.js"></script>
  <div class="down-btn">
    <a href="#section">&darr;</a>
  </div>
  <section id="section">
    SECTION
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

(Mouse left click : move forward / right click : move backward)
I implemented almost done except change mesh.

Is it possible or any solution about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Want you want is a typical Level of Detail (LoD) behavior, right? Have a look at this three.js example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=Lod#webgl_lod and docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/LOD

Comment: @Brakebein Little different. My case is change to 100% different mesh.

Comment: You can change to 100% the mesh. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [THREE.LOD()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/LOD) (Level of Detail) to replace the a mesh by another mesh at a certain distance.

The example (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod) uses only same type of geometry for the different distances. But if you look into the code, each distance has its own geometry and mesh instance.

And so can you, to change to 100% different mesh.

```js
// create meshes and LOD objects

for ( let i = 0; i < 800; i ++ ) {

  let lod = new THREE.LOD();

  let sprite = new THREE.TextSprite(...);

  let squareGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2,2),
      squareMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(),
      square = new THREE.Mesh(squareGeo, squareMat);

  lod.addLevel(sprite, 1);
  lod.addLevel(square, 100); // will be visible from 100 and beyond

  lod.position.x = Math.random() * 180-100;
  lod.position.y = Math.random() * 180-100;
  lod.position.z = Math.random() * 1000-40;

  group.add(lod);
}

// animation loop
function animate() {

  // ...

  group.children.forEach(function (child) {
    // LOD update
    child.update(camera);

    // opacity
    var distance = camera.position.distanceTo(child.position);
    var opacity = -1 / 400 * distance + 1;
    if (opacity < 0) {
      opacity = 0;
    }
    child.getObjectForDistance(distance).material.opacity = opacity;

  });

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

**EDIT:** [LOD class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/LOD.js) modification for smooth transition

```js
addLevel: function ( object, distance, fadeDistance ) {

    ...

    levels.splice( l, 0, { distance: distance, fadeDistance: fadeDistance || distance, object: object } );

    ...

}

update: function () {

    ...

    levels[ 0 ].object.visible = true;
    levels[ 0 ].object.material.opacity = 1.0;

    for ( var i = 1, l = levels.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

        if ( distance >= levels[ i ].distance && distance < levels[ i ].fadeDistance ) {

            levels[ i ].object.visible = true;

            var t = (distance - levels[i].distance) / (levels[i].fadeDistance - levels[i].distance);
            levels[ i - 1 ].object.material.opacity = 1.0 - t;
            levels[ i ].object.material.opacity = t;

        } else if ( distance >= levels[ i ].fadeDistance ) {

            levels[ i - 1 ].object.visible = false;
            levels[ i ].object.visible = true;
            levels[ i ].object.material.opacity = 1.0;

        } else {

            break;

        }

    }

    ...

}
```

Of course, `material.transparent` property of objects should be set `true`, so opacity will work.

Adding square to LOD object

```js
lod.addLevel(sprite, 1);
lod.addLevel(star, 100, 140); // will fade in at distance of 100 to 140, fully visible beyond 140
lod.addLevel(dummy, 200, 400); // if dummy is an object with empty geometry, star will fade out between 200 and 400
```

Remove opacity modification in animation loop.

Comment: Works perfectly. However, change is so rough. Can it change smoothly?

Comment: I want to insert smooth change animation.

Comment: Well, not out of the box. You would need to modify the LOD class, so that on update it does not just set visibility, but also interpolates the opacity of two objects within a certain distance range.

Comment: You mean that, there is no default property about animation, right? So, I have to modify LOD js file.

Comment: Yes. I have updated my answer. That's how I would modify the LOD class. If I'm not missing something important, it should work something like this.

Comment: I run it -> https://teamhide.github.io/stack/

and source code -> https://github.com/teamhide/stack

Comment: Nice. But as I said: in your animation loop you should just call `child.update(camera);` and remove opacity stuff, because opacity is set within the update method. And the material of your star should also to be set `transparent = true`, if you want this fading behavior.

Comment: In my personal work, I try it last day. I think it works something difference with my expected result. My goal is fade in/out when objects change to objects. (Just that moment). It means that object change to another object with smooth animation. Is it possible thing to implement?

Comment: Also changed code and result here ->

result : https://teamhide.github.io/stack2/

code : https://github.com/teamhide/stack2

Comment: I made a pull request with some corrections. It should now work as expected.

Comment: It is very helpful if you comment some explanation about your code. But if it is hard, it just ok. I will analyze it :)